# Multidimensional Array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

This is my array:

```
Array
(
    [Soorten] => Array
    (
        [Soort] => inpandig
    )

    [Voorzieningen] => Array
    (
        [Voorziening] => Array
        (
            [0] => voorzien van verwarming
            [1] => voorzien van elektra
            [2] => voorzien van water
            [3] => met elektrische deur
        )
    )

    [Capaciteit] => 1
    (
        [Isolatievormen] => Array
        (
            [Isolatie] => volledig geïsoleerd
        )
    )
```

How can I display it in PHP, like this:

```
Voorziening:
voorzien van verwarming
voorzien van elektra
voorzien van water
met elektrische deur

Isolatie:
volledig geïsoleerd
```

etc.

Comment: You should read a PHP manual... assoziative arrays is your hint. http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: A nested `foreach`, as in `foreach ($outer as $k=>$o) { foreach ($inner as $i)} }`

Comment: as most of us are not dutch, try to give english examples. It isn't necessary most of the times, but it makes it easier to comprehend what you are doing, also for non-dutchies :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [recursive function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29) would do the trick:

```
$array = array(
    'Soorten' => array('Soort' => 'inpandig'), 
    'Voorzieningen' => array('Voorziening' => array('voorzien van verwarming', 'voorzien van elektra', 'voorzien van water', 'met elektrische deur')));
printArray($array);

function printArray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            echo $key . "<br/>";
            printArray($value);
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
Soorten
inpandig

Voorzieningen
Voorziening
voorzien van verwarming
voorzien van elektra
voorzien van water
met elektrische deur
```